Expected homogenous image collection error in GEE
I've a piece of code that I've have used without any issue and errors in the past 3 months. Suddenly however I began receiving the below error.
Could anybody assist me on how to fix this?
I really don't know what the issue is since I am using the exact same collection.
Link to full code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8aeeab3a5970758b4291dc5f1ceaf0ac

Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with
incompatible bands was encountered:   First image type: 26 bands ([B1,
B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, B11, B12, AOT, WVP, SCL, TCI_R,
TCI_G, TCI_B, MSK_CLDPRB, MSK_SNWPRB, QA10, QA20, QA60,
MSK_CLASSI_OPAQUE, MSK_CLASSI_CIRRUS, MSK_CLASSI_SNOW_ICE]). Current
image type: 26 bands ([B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, B11,
B12, AOT, WVP, SCL, TCI_R, TCI_G, TCI_B, QA10, QA20, QA60,
MSK_CLASSI_OPAQUE, MSK_CLASSI_CIRRUS, MSK_CLASSI_SNOW_ICE, MSK_CLDPRB,
MSK_SNWPRB]).
Image ID: null Some bands might require explicit casts.

